# Getting Aggregate Statistics from Individual Realm Records

Tags: swift, realm

I'm trying to get aggregate data for individual Realm records so that it can be graphed on a chart.

I have a 'WorkDay' Realm Object which stores values like 'startTime', 'endTime', 'singleTimeIncome', 'penaltyIncome', 'totalIncome', etc.

A charting example is that I want to collect the 'totalIncome' of all Work Days for an entire year and graph that against the 'totalIncome' for all Work Days of previous years.

My current approach is to cycle all WorkDay Realm Objects for a given year with a 'for loop' and store the values from WorkDay in a custom data struct. I move the values from the Realm WorkDay Object to an array in the data struct. The reason I want to add them into an array as it will then allow me to calculate things like 'averageTotalIncome' for that year as well as getting the 'totalIncome' for the entire year by running 'reduce(0, +)' on the array.

The custom data struct looks similar to this:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftDate

struct TimePeriodData {
    
    //MARK: - Time Period
    
    var timePeriod: TimePeriod = .week
    var date: Date = Date()
    var localDate: Date = Date()
    
    //MARK: - Work Day Times
    
    var startTimeArray: [Date] = []
    var endTimeArray: [Date] = []
    
    //MARK: - Work Day Hours
    
    var hoursSingleTimeArray: [Double] = []
    var hoursPenaltyArray: [Double] = []
    var hoursTotalArray: [Double] = []
    
    //MARK: - Work Day Income
    
    var singleTimeIncomeArray: [Double] = []
    var penaltyIncomeArray: [Double] = []
    var totalIncomeArray: [Double] = []
}
```

I then collect all Work Days from the Realm, the function looks like this:

```
private func updateWorkDays() {
    // Get Time Period Dates
    let start = timePeriodStart()
    let end = timePeriodEnd()
    
    // Get Current User Work Days for Time Period
    let allUserWorkDays = realm.objects(WorkDay.self).where { workDay in
        workDay.date.contains(start ... end)
    }
    workDays = allUserWorkDays
}
```

Once I have the Work Days I then move the data into 'TimePeriodData' which will be used by SwiftUI to generate charts, etc. The code look something like this:

```
private func getData(for inputDate: Date, from inputWorkDays: Results<WorkDay>) -> TimePeriodData {
    var data = TimePeriodData()
    for workDay in inputWorkDays {
        // Time Period
        data.timePeriod = self.timePeriod
        data.date = inputDate
        data.localDate = workDayListBrain.getLocalDate(from: inputDate)
        
        // Work Day Times
        data.startTimeArray.append(workDay.startTime)
        data.endTimeArray.append(workDay.endTime)
        
        // Work Day Hours
        data.hoursSingleTimeArray.append(workDay.hoursSingleTime)
        data.hoursPenaltyArray.append(workDay.hoursPenalty)
        data.hoursTotalArray.append(workDay.hoursTotal)
        
        // Work Day Income
        data.singleTimeIncomeArray.append(workDay.singleTimeIncome)
        data.penaltyIncomeArray.append(workDay.penaltyIncome)

    }
    return data
}
```

When 'getData' returns the UI is updated. However what I am finding is that when I use 'getData' for an entire year I need to cycle 100 Work Day Objects and this takes around 2 Seconds. I know I will need to create 'TimePeriodData' for previous years as well so there is other data to graph against, assuming each of which will take 2 Seconds if they have 100 Work Days. This adds up quickly.

I've read other posts where people cycle 50,000 Realm Objects and it takes 0.1 Seconds. Given I am only cycling 100 and it takes two seconds, am I doing something fundamentally wrong here? Is there a better way to approach this?

What I have tried to date is using a map function instead of a 'for loop', this looks a bit like this:

```
    data.startTimeArray = inputWorkDays.compactMap { workDay in workDay.startTime } as [Date]
    data.endTimeArray = inputWorkDays.compactMap { workDay in workDay.endTime } as [Date]
```

But the 'compactMap' made no notable gains in speed. I also tried doing it all on a BG Thread, this made things 'feel' speedier as the UI was never stalled while processing data but it still took 2 Seconds to update.

Any help or advice you could offer would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Cross post to the Realm Forums [here](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/getting-aggregate-statistics-from-individual-realm-records/195262)

Answer (score 0):

There's a much more detailed answer on the Realm forums but I will include the gist of it here.

There are a few issues with the code in the question but the biggest culprit is iterating over data repeatedly - this will cause delays but also, because it's on the main thread will pause the UI.

Based on the question, all of the points needed can be done via single queries that are not only fast, but require no iterating. For example, we can let Realm do the heavy, memory friendly lifting with aggregate functions; something like this

```
let sum: Double = realm.objects(WorkDay.self).sum(ofProperty: "hoursSingleTime")
```

Here's how that could be implemented in the `getData` function instead of a loop:

```
private var getData(inputDate: date, startDate: Date, endDate: Date) - > {
    var data = TimePeriodData()

    data.timePeriod = //use startDate and endDate
    data.date = inputDate
    data.localDate = workDayListBrain.getLocalDate(from: inputDate)
    
    data.singleTimeTotal: Double = realm.objects(WorkDay.self)
       .where { $0.startDate >= startDate && $0.endDate <= endDate }.sum(ofProperty: "hoursSingleTime")
        
   data.penaltyIncomeTotal: Double = realm.objects(WorkDay.self)
       .where { $0.startDate >= startDate && $0.endDate <= endDate }.sum(ofProperty: "penaltyIncome")
    
    //... the rest of the totals
    return data
}
```

Two other questions came up; one about averages when objects have nil values and then median values. Let me address them here

Averages with nil (where the WorkDay object `driveAway` is optional

```
//average driveAway taking nils into account
let results = realm.objects(WorkDay.self).where { $0.driveAway != nil }
let count = results.count
let countDouble = Double(count)
let total: Double = results.sum(ofProperty: "driveAway")
print("Average: \(total / countDouble)")
```

and then median values (incorporate nil handling filter per above if needed)

```
//find median of hoursSingleTime
let allResults = realm.objects(WorkDay.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "hoursSingleTime")
let allCount = allResults.count
let countIsEvenNum = allCount.isMultiple(of: 2) //even or odd number

if countIsEvenNum == true {
    print("even num")
    //get the objects values above and below the 'middle' index,
    //  add together and divide by 2. Leaving this as a code exercise for brevity

} else { //handle where the count of objects is odd so there's a middle object
    let middleIndex = allCount / 2
    let medianWork = allResults[middleIndex]
    print("Median is: \(medianWork.hoursSingleTime)")
}
```